# Integration tests on Spring Boot: webEnvironment required?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit

## EDIT

I also tried to add

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

as suggested in [this official Spring Blog page](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles), but nothing

---

I created some integration tests, that tests methods of some repositories. I found that without:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,
    classes = ********.class
)
```

the tests don't run. I tried also with `WebEnvironment.NONE`, but I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

I don't understand why the web environment is required. Is there not a way to run an integration test on repositories without running the web environment?

Comment: For integration test, you would need the app running, right? Hence you would require the web environment for the spring boot app to run. Or am I not understanding your query right?

Comment: But repositories does not require the web app. I think I only need to pass an ApplicationContext, but I don't know how.

Comment: @MadhuBhat I updated the question

Comment: What is the reason for `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`? Have you configured a test datasource and in memory database or something?

Comment: @ngueno Yes I configured a test datasource in a test application.config, but it's not an in memory db (unluckily...). The message disappear when I use a web environment...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the problem is using @EnableSwagger2.Check the following link.

[Spring boot service layer integration test with WebEnvironment.NONE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718334/spring-boot-service-layer-integration-test-with-webenvironment-none-not-working)