# Spring boot service layer integration test with WebEnvironment.NONE not working

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

I want to integration test of service layer without web layer but it not working in following config:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
```

Just after changing webEnvironment to `RANDOM_PORT` it works.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RoutingApiApplication.class}, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
```

Following error occurs:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: are there any stacktrace in the not working case ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that it's because of using springfox annotation  `@EnableSwagger2`, Activate springfox only when web environment is available.
The error is issued here:

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2329